# what is the best way to use a custom json converter to convert a complex object?

Tags: json

I'm using asp.net core to create a webapi project.

When an object is posted to my action, I want to use the custom converter to analyse the json object first.And then create an instance of a child class. For the child, instance I only want to customize one property. So the question is, what if the object gets complex, I want to use the standard conversion to get the whole object, and manually manipulate one property.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Could whoever down-voted this question justify his action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. For all the properties that you don't want to use custom deserialization you can still use the string.ToObject() to convert. Just do not use ToObject method on the very class that you originally created the converter for. It will craete an infinite loop trying to convert itself again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add only the properties you want to your View Model, the rest will be ignored.